# Replace , by . In sql / pl sql

Tags: sql, excel, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I execute this code on Oracle!

The objective is to replace the , with a . in the price.
The problem is when I generate the xls file, if a price is for example 0,1 , I get .1 ! I think oracle eliminates the 0!

[image]

How can I fix this?

```
select 
'"'||arccode||'"'  "ean_code",
'"'||artcexr||'"'  as "product_id",
'"'||to_char(artdcre,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'"'  as "created_at",
'"'||null||'"'  "brand",
'"'||null||'"'  "description",
'"'||replace(PKPRIXVENTE.GET_PRIX_VENTE(arvcinv,207,1,sysdate),',','.')||'"'  as "price",
from  artrac
```

Comment: I Think there is not need to replace the "," in the query, your excel is formating the column is US format (which is using "." as separator. 

You can concatenate your "PKPRIXVENTE.GET_PRIX_VENTE" with ''''
for expl  : concat( '''', PKPRIXVENTE.GET_PRIX_VENTE)

Comment: I don’t want to edit the solution on excel ! I want the solution to be done when i generate my query on oracle !

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has nothing to do with it. The way that excel initialy shows the numbers depends on some regional settingss in windows.
Windows 11:
search for 'currency' and click on "Change the way currency is displayed"
[image]

On the screen below click on Additional settings
[image]
... and you can change the way that numbers are displayed
including leading zeros and everything else...
[image]

Windows 10: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/customize-numbers-format-on-windows-10.html
Regards...

Comment: I already have this setting , and the query is edited by oracle before the extraction ! I edited the answer to see how the price  look like in oracle

Comment: Yes, I see now that your values are in quotes so excel treats them as text. You should format them as numbers and export them as numbers for excel to show it as numbers. If you are sending numbers then: format them like TO_NUMBER('100.00', '9G999D99'), and if it is a part of concatination string then To_Char(TO_NUMBER('100.00', '9G999D99')).